# How to Append string to an Existing XML file

Tags: c#, xml

The Below is my XMl File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">      
      <string>PipeFabricationAddin</string>
      <string>IntegratorAddin</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
```

I'm new to a XML world using C#.. is there any way to append `<string> Something </string>`  inside the `<ArrayOfString></ArrayOfString>?`

What I want is this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">      
      <string>PipeFabricationAddin</string>
      <string>C:\AVEVA\Plant\PDMS12.1.SP4\PDMSAddin\PEDASConverter_PDMS</string> !!! i want this line to be added!!!
      <string>IntegratorAddin</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
```

thanks for reading my question.

Comment: please check xml document library in C#. It has methods for Nodes. For writing in file check System.IO library.

Comment: you can iterate through the nodes of XML and can append and modify as your wish.

Comment: If you are using [XMLDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-6.0), it should be easy with all the available methods like `AppendChild`, `CreateNode` etc

Comment: As an alternative to XmlDocument, you might have a look at [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply with `XDocument`

```cs
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);   // alternatively XDocuemnt.Parse

xDoc.Root.Elements()
    .First(e => e.Value == "PipeFabricationAddin")
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("string", "C:\AVEVA\Plant\PDMS12.1.SP4\PDMSAddin\PEDASConverter_PDMS"));

xDoc.Save(filePath);
```